# Specifying multiple storage accounts for Kusto export

Tags: azure-data-explorer

ADX export command supports specifying multiple destination storage accounts such as the following example taken from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage):-

```
.export
  async compressed
  to csv (
    h@"https://storage1.blob.core.windows.net/containerName;secretKey",
    h@"https://storage1.blob.core.windows.net/containerName2;secretKey"
  ) with (
    sizeLimit=100000,
    namePrefix=export,
    includeHeaders=all,
    encoding =UTF8NoBOM
  )
  <| myLogs | where id == "moshe" | limit 10000
```

I can understand that this is probably to avoid throttling. But I am not able to figure out how this is generally taken advantage of. Ideally what follows next after this sort of export is some big data framework (e.g. Databricks , Hadoop etc.) that is going to read and process it. But these frameworks typically require data for a single partition to exist in a fixed storage account for them to be able to process the partition , not distributed across multiple storage accounts. Complete separate partitions can reside in different storage accounts but not a single partition data divided among separate storages. Otherwise there has to be a costly process layer on top of Kusto export , which will bring all data for a single partition to a single storage account. So my question is -- given that the data is exported specifying multiple storage accounts like the example shows , how to really read this from partitioned big data processing , what's the recommendation here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ADX supports multiple storage accounts being specified in an .export command specifically to avoid throttling. This is somewhat similar to disk striping. In fact, ADX itself can easily consume data exported in this fashion (for example, if an external table is defined over the same set of storage accounts).

For tools other than ADX to consume this data, there are several choices:

1. Use a tool that supports this model.
2. Alternatively, consume the data per each storage account (for example, import it into the tool from each storage account in a loop).
3. Last, build some pipeline that will move all data into a single storage account or some other storage (perhaps not even blob storage).

Comment: So in that case lets say I export to an external table which has multiple containers of the same storage account (ADLS Gen2) specified in its definition , will it help throttling , or it will be better to have totally separate storage accounts altogether?